# Number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $D_{2n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

The question is from Dummit and Foote pg146, Exercise 12.

> Let $2n=2^ak$ where $k$ is odd. Prove that the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $D_{2n}$ is $k$.

This is my attempt.

> My Attempt: The order of the Sylow $2$-subgroup must be $2^a$, and obviously $P \leq N_{D_{2n}}(P)$. So, by Sylow's theorem, $$n_2=[G:N_{D_{2n}}(P)]\equiv 1\pmod{2}$$
> Since $[G:N_{D_{2n}}(P)]\geq [G: P]=k$, and $n_2$ is odd, we must conclude that $n_2=k$

However, the hint in the question suggests me to prove that $N_{D_{2n}}(P)=P$. I can get that result **after** I get the answer, not the other way around as the question suggests. How would I get the result $N_{D_{2n}}(P)=P$ first?

Comment: Sylow's theorem tells us that $n_2$ divides $k$. (i.e. $[G:N_{D_{2n}}(P)]$ divides $[G:P]$. So you cannot conclude that $n_2=k$.

Comment: Since $P\subseteq N_G(P)$, you have the wrong inequality with the indices: $[G:P]=[G:N_G(P)][N_G(P):P]$, so $[G:P]\geq [G:N_G(P)]$.

Comment: $$P \le N_G(P) \implies |P| \le |N_G(P)| \implies |G|/|N_G(P)| \le |G|/|P| \implies [G : N_G(P)] \le [G : P].$$

Comment: @daruma  Ohh....I was dumb...Then how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks everybody for pointing my mistake out! I'm new to group theory so I get things confused a lot...

Comment: $D_{2n}=D_{2^ak}$ is the transformation group of the regular $2^{a-1}k$-gon. Now, if you think of it this way, the Sylow subgroups have a very concrete interpretation as the transformation group of a regular $2^{a-1}$-gon inscribed in the $2^{a-1}k$-gon.

Comment: @daruma I'm sorry but I don't think I got the last sentence. I get that $2^{a-1}$-gons can be inscribed in the $2^{a-1}k$-gon by checking vertices of every $k$th vertex, but how would that help in interpreting this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me be more explicit about what I meant in the comments. If you label your vertices from $1$ to $2^{a-1}k$, you can get a regular $2^{a-1}$-gon by taking the vertices $i, i+k, i+2k,..., i+2^{a-2}k$ for $i\in \{1,..., k-1\}$. This gives us $k$ distinct $2^{a-1}$-gon each of which has symmetry group $D_{2^{a}}$. These are indeed the desired Sylow subgroups. So, we have that $n_2=k$.

Comment: Oh...thanks., I get what you were saying. Just one thing; I think you were going to write $i\in \{1,..., k-1, k\}$, right?

Comment: Oh, I did indeed get my indices wrong!